# Disable rest-client output on minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, rest-client, webmock

I've searched for this, but without success.

I have some tests (minitest) that use RestClient and Webmock. When passing for those tests I always have the request logged, polluting the test ouput:

```
[$] rake                                                                                                 

Run options: --seed 60435

Running:
.........................................................RestClient.get "http://example.com/some_controller/some_action?userLocale=fr_FR", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "User-Agent"=>"rest-client/2.0.0 (darwin14.1.0 x86_64) ruby/2.2.1p85" # => 200 OK |  4 bytes
```

Is there a way to disable this ?

**[EDIT]**

Just to add, if I call the same address using ruby URL I have nothing logged (even using webmock) so it really is something related with Rest-client.

I already tried to set the `ENV['RESTCLIENT_LOG']` variable, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
RestClient.stub :log, '' do
  # Your test code here
end
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub

You have many other options to redirect the log output:

- In your `test_helper.rb`:

  ```
  RestClient.log = 'tmp/test.log'
  ```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.8.0/RestClient.log=

- From the command line:

  ```
  RESTCLIENT_LOG=tmp/restclient.log bundle exec rails test
  ```

In **last resort** you could monkey patch:

```
# test_helper.rb
RestClient.class_eval do
  def self.log
    ''
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe i'ts  a workaround, but not what I'm looking for. It would be necessary to change all tests that use this, and keep in mind to do it every new test using rest-lcient.